# API Platform with OAUTH/ OPENID CONNECT PROVIDER

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak, api-platform.com

I work on API Platform as simple API and it's pretty easy to use !

Because I have other applications which use Keycloak as OpenID provider I need to integrate a Oauth2 provider or a Keycloak Provider ....

I see in configuration in docs  there is a key "oauth" and we can specify clientId, secret and other values but I don't know where this conf is use. There isn't a 403 but still 200 with "enabled: true" on requests...

May be I could use this provider 
https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak for Symfony but I don't understand where I can add it in API Platform.

I'm only a beginner on apiPlatform and in Symfony Too.

If Someone could help me... It would be awazing !
Thank You (modifié)

Comment: Which grant types are being supported by Keycloak?